# after using pd.to_datetime columns used years as seconds

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have used pd.to_datetime in order to transform column however I got years as seconds

Here is the code:

```
df['Year_Birth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year_Birth'])
```

What should I add In order to fix this

This is how it appears in data frame after using pd.to_datetime

[image]

Comment: use `pd.to_datetime(df['Year_Birth'], format='%Y')` - otherwise, pandas will assume your input is Unix time, not years.